# Reg: Installation of FHIR 5.2.0

Tags: javascript

I am very new to the hapi-fhir, I have download source (hapi-fhir-5.2.0-standard-distribution) from below link. I am trying to deploy the server on localhost.

https://github.com/hapifhir/hapi-fhir/releases/tag/v5.2.0

OS: ubuntu 16.04
java version: 1.8.0_275

Please help me with deployment procedure ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to play with a FHIR server, I'd recommend learning the resources, search params, etc. using a public reference server, e.g. http://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/

If indeed you need to get started locally, try the Docker installation of the jpa server: https://github.com/hapifhir/hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter#running-via-docker-hub

The CapabilityStatement will tell you what the server can do: http://localhost:8080/fhir/metadata

To search a resource: http://localhost:8080/fhir/ (e.g. http://localhost:8080/fhir/Patient)

The server will be empty, so you'll need to POST/import data.